# Using gawk or sed to inplace change line after or before every other match

Tags: perl, awk, sed, comments

I am trying to change the comment format for many files. Currently I have

```
//-----------------------------------------------------------
//   NAME : Class
//   DESCRIPTION : Vague information
//-----------------------------------------------------------
```

The number of `-` may be different with each file, or even with each case. I would like something like this to keep readability with the rest of the code while still allowing compatibility with a documenting program:

```
//-----------------------------------------------------------
/*!
//   NAME : Class
//   DESCRIPTION : Vague information
*/
//-----------------------------------------------------------
```

But this is also acceptable, and for sure easier:

```
/*!
//   NAME : Class
//   DESCRIPTION : Vague information
*/
```

For a start, I have tried something like

`$ gawk -i inplace '/^\/\/--.*/&&v++%2 {sub(/^\/\/--.*, "\/\*!")}'  filename.cpp`
and then
`$ gawk -i inplace '/^\/\/--.*/{sub(/^\/\/--.*, "\*\/")}'  filename.cpp`

which obviously has some syntax errors; the goal was to change every odd instance of `//---*` with `/*!`, and then replacing `//---*` with `*/`, and for just one file, instead of many .cpp and .h/.hpp files.

Comment: So leave those `//---` with as many `---` as they have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given:

```
$ cat file
//-----------------------------------------------------------
//   NAME : Class
//   DESCRIPTION : Vague information
//-----------------------------------------------------------
```

With [THIS](https://regex101.com/r/n8LL3c/1) regex, you can use perl:

```
$ perl -0777 -pE 's/^(\/\/-+\R)(\/\/[\s\S]*?)(^\/\/-+\R?)/\1\/\*!\n\2\*\/\n\3/gm' file 
//-----------------------------------------------------------
/*!
//   NAME : Class
//   DESCRIPTION : Vague information
*/
//-----------------------------------------------------------
```

Perl also has an [inplace](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun#-i%5Bextension%5D) option.

Comment: `$ find . -type f -name "*.fileextension" -exec {your command without file at the end} {} \;` worked very well for getting multiple files. As an aside, that regex site is also brilliant.

Answer (score 2):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -E 'N;s~-\n~&/*!\n~;s~\n/+-~\n*/&~' input_file
//-----------------------------------------------------------
/*!
//   NAME : Class
//   DESCRIPTION : Vague information
*/
//-----------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 2):

```
perl -0777 -wnE'
    say s{ //-+\n\K (//.*?) (//-+\n) }{/*!\n$1*/\n$2}sgrx
' file_with_comment_blocks.txt
```

Broken into lines only for readability. Modifiers (at the end of regex) are:

- `s` with it the `.` matches a newline as well
- `g` repeat throughout the whole string ("global")
- `r` so to return the new string (or the unchanged original). Used here for printing
- `x` ignore spaces, so use them for readability (also allows newlines and `#`-comments)

This only prints so it can be redirected to a file for a result while it is safe for testing.

Or, change so to rewrite the file in-place

```
perl -0777 -i.bak -wnE'
    s{ //-+\n\K (//.*?) (//-+\n) }{/*!\n$1*/\n$2}sgx
' file_with_comment_blocks.txt
```

If backup isn't wanted then use `-i` (no `.bak`).  See [*Command-line switches* in perlrun](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun#Command-Switches)

Answer (score 0):

I would harness GNU `AWK` for this task following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
//-----------------------------------------------------------
//   NAME : Class
//   DESCRIPTION : Vague information
//-----------------------------------------------------------
```

then

```
awk 'index($0,"//---")==1{++v;if(v%2){print;print "/*!"}else{print "*/";print};next}{print}' file.txt
```

gives output

```
//-----------------------------------------------------------
/*!
//   NAME : Class
//   DESCRIPTION : Vague information
*/
//-----------------------------------------------------------
```

Explanation: for lines starting with `//---` (I use [`index` String function](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) to avoid need to escape `/`) I do increase `v` by `1` and then print current line followed by `/*!` in case `v` is odd else print `*/` followed by current line, then I instruct GNU `AWK` to go to `next` line to avoid duplicate `print`ing, all others lines are just `print`ed. After you are sure result is compliant with requirement you might add `-i inplace` after `awk`.

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.0.1)*

Answer (score 0):

Using any awk:

```
$ awk '/^\/\/-+$/{ $0=( ++c%2 ? "/*!" : "*/" ) } 1' file
/*!
//   NAME : Class
//   DESCRIPTION : Vague information
*/
```

or if you prefer:

```
$ awk '/^\/\/-+$/{ $0=( ++c%2 ? $0 ORS "/*!" : "*/" ORS $0 ) } 1' file
//-----------------------------------------------------------
/*!
//   NAME : Class
//   DESCRIPTION : Vague information
*/
//-----------------------------------------------------------
```

To change the input file, if you have GNU awk change `awk` to `awk -i inplace` or with any awk add `>tmp && mv tmp file` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^\/\/-\+$/{:a;N;/\n\/\/-\+$/!ba;s/\n.*\n/\n\/*!&*\/\n/}' file
```

Gather up lines that start and end `//----------...`.

Prepend `\n/*!` and append `*/\n` between the first and last newline of the collection.

Or if prefered:

```
sed '/^\/\/-\+$/{:a;N;/\n\/\/-\+$/!ba;s/^[^\n]*/\/*!/;s/\(.*\n\).*/\1*\//}' file
```

A "belt a braces" version of the first solution, that only applies to lines that begin and end as OP example with all lines commented inbetween:

```
sed '/^\/\/-\+$/{:a;N;/\n\/\/[^\n]*$/!{:b;P;D}
     /\n\/\/-\+$/!ba;s/\n.*\n/\n\/*!&*\/\n/;Tb}' file
```